# how to send mail to another mail from my mail server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want send mail to users which register in my web site.I have an mail server which name is muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net and my code is below

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net")
    MailMessage mailim = new MailMessage();
    mailim.From = new MailAddress("muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net");
    mailim.To.Add("registered user's mail");
    mailim.Subject = "Activation code";
    mailim.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailim.Body = "<a href=\"http://www.bisorumvar.net/Uyelik_Onayla.aspx?mail=" + mail + "\">Please click this link to activate your registiration</a>";
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net", "xxx");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
    SmtpServer.Send(mailim);
}
```

when I click the button it doesnt show any errors but it doesnt send mail to user's mail adress so where is there any error anybody help please

Comment: You should change your password, _right now_.

Comment: Your activation email doesn't add any security; attackers can trivially forge the link.

Comment: `muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net` is not an SMTP server.

Comment: yes what should I change smtpserver with my code

Comment: As @SLaks already pointed out you need to update the SMTP server to something like mail.bisorumvar.net or whatever is the name of your SMTP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you wrote:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net")
```

`muratakarsu@bisorumvar.net` is not a server.  This is an email address.

According to nslookup you the mail server for your domain is the following:

- antispam1.ihs.com.tr 94.138.192.240
- antispam2.ihs.com.tr 94.138.192.241

Here is an example of how to use nslookup:

[image]

So the correct code would be:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("antispam1.ihs.com.tr")
```